# Why do I need 300 points to add the "pairing" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, reputation, privileges

I just asked this question:
[Problem pairing again Nexus 5 with Alpine car stereo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59554/problem-pairing-a-device-that-was-previosult-pair-on-nexus-5)
and added (correctly) the "pairing" tag but was informed by the system that I needed 300 points to add that tag - it then suggest a list of other tags I was allowed to use.  NONE of which was appropriate - 'pairing' IS appropriate.

So, why doe this site not allow me, a user with over 10000 points on SO and a moderator on the newly defunct OnStartups stack exchange site, to add a pretty basic tag - which would actually help the question get classified better and help people give/find the right answer?

Comment: We already have a [bluetooth-pairing tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-pairing). I don't know that I can say much about the "why", but I guess an SE rep might be able to provide some information. Presumably it's to prevent new users from creating unnecessary tags (or typo tags), which still manages to happen fairly regularly even with the 300 rep threshold in place. Rep from other sites doesn't apply to other privileges either; are you suggesting the "create tags" one should be an exception?

Comment: Ah, I see - I thought pairing was already created - but it is not - it is bluetooth-pairing.  I didn't read carefully enough.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Tags and their structure are very site specific. A user should have some knowledge on how a site does organize its tags in order to create new one. That's one reason why you need 300 rep here and why it doesn't matter what position or how much rep you have on other sites.